# Assign public IP only with CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm using CloudFormation to create an EC2 instance.
What I am trying to achieve is only assign a public IP. No private IP.
Everything gets created fine and it creates a DNS entry for the public IP, but it also creates a private IP. How can I tell it to not create a private IP.
Here is my template:

```
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Properties:
      ImageId:
        Ref: ImageId
      InstanceType:
        Ref: InstanceType
      KeyName:
        Ref: KeyName
      NetworkInterfaces:
      - GroupSet:
        - Ref: GroupId
        DeviceIndex: 0
        DeleteOnTermination: true
        SubnetId:
          Ref: SubnetId
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  DnsRecord:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: !Ref 'HostedZoneName'
      Comment: DNS name for my instance.
      Name: !Join ['', [!Ref 'Subdomain', ., !Ref 'HostedZoneName']]
      Type: A
      TTL: '300'
      ResourceRecords:
      - !GetAtt EC2Instance.PublicIp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always have private IP. Is there any problem with that on your side?